# Using layout_weight with ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place an ImageView in the middle of the screen, with the aim of putting other views above and below it so I have decided to use a LinearLayout (vertical) and a LinearLayout (horizontal). However, when I use layout_weight for the ImageView, the image disappears completely (a blank screen is shown). The ImageView's image is set in onCreate(). I would like the ImageView to take up 50% of the width of the screen, hence my use of weights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="2">

<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/albumArtImageView"></ImageView>

    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `layout_weight` to be useful for anything, there needs to be left-over space. Your first view under the top LinearLayout has `layout_height="fill_parent"`. That takes up all the room. Try setting `layout_height="0dp"` everywhere that you want the dimension determined by the `layout_weight` and I think your results will be better.

Comment: apparently I'm not allowed to have integer types when I try to set layout_height="0"

Comment: Ack. I always make that mistake. I'm correcting my answer so someone else doesn't trip over it as well.

Answer (score -1):

try to change the orientation of second linearlayout to vertical

Comment: This would then prevent me from having gaps either side of the ImageView, wouldn't it? This is not what I am looking for in this case.